# Google Analytics - Goal not being logged

Tags: google, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a URL on my site where a user is re-directed to once an order is completed. I can see the URL showing up the the Analytics logs, but the goal is not being logged.

My the complete URL is `http://www.mydomain.com/Store/OrderComplete` and I have entered `"/Store/OrderCompleted"` in goal tracking and selected "head match".

Why is the goal not getting logged?

Answer (score 4):

The URL is OrderComplete and the goal tracking is OrderCompleted (d at the end). Drop the d on the goal and it should work.